# \textsuperscript does not work

Tags: superscripts

I am writing my thesis using a template and have a problem with the function `\textsuperscript`. For whatever reason it is not working and instead it writes "germanb".

I mean, if I write in latex `10\textsuperscript{2} km\textsuperscript{2}` the processed text reads "10germanb2 kmgermanb2".

Has anyone seen this before? Is there a solution or another command? I  don't want to change all superscripts to equations.

Comment: Please write a minimal working example. See [link](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/250119) for more details what it means.

Comment: I thought of doing so, but it is a thesis and the template is quite complex. I'd need to send the complete preamble too, right?

Comment: That obviously should not happen and in fact it did not happen for me in a small example I just compiled. Your best bet of getting a good answer here is to show us a small example document that reproduces the undesirable behaviour with as little code as possible (a so-called MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864).

Comment: Start with a copy of your document, remove everything but the line that creates the problem, do the same with the preamble removing half of it recursively --- until you have a minimal example showing the problem. During this bisection exercise, chances are you'll find the source of the error by yourself... ;-)

Comment: That all said, for your example I'd use `siunitx` and `\qty[parse-numbers=false]{10^{2}}{\square\kilo\metre}` (or `\SI` instead of `\qty` if you are using an older `siunitx`).

Comment: there is no answer anyone can give currently. For example I could guess that your document class has `\def\textsuperscript{germanb}`  . Certainly _some_ code you are running is effectively that. But where that is in your document is impossible to say.

Comment: @moewe or, with `siunitx`, `\num{e2}`  which is even faster to type; you probably need `\sisetup{mode=text, print-unity-mantissa=false}`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This document

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[german]{babel}

\renewcommand\textsuperscript{\tmpa}

\begin{document}

10\textsuperscript{2} km\textsuperscript{2}

\end{document}
```

produces the output shown:

[image]

The bad line may not be quite so explicit in your case, but buried in a package, but you could debug by adding lines as follows:

```
\typeout{1: \meaning\textsuperscript}
\documentclass{article}
\typeout{2: \meaning\textsuperscript}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\typeout{3: \meaning\textsuperscript}
\renewcommand\textsuperscript{\tmpa}
\typeout{4: \meaning\textsuperscript}

\begin{document}

\typeout{5: \meaning\textsuperscript}
10\textsuperscript{2} km\textsuperscript{2}

\end{document}
```

this makes the same typeset output but the terminal and log show:

```
1: macro:->\protect \textsuperscript  
2: macro:->\protect \textsuperscript  
3: macro:->\protect \textsuperscript  
4: \long macro:->\tmpa
```

which clearly shows that `\textsuperscript` went wrong between the 3rd and 4th `\typeout`

Comment: This is absolutely right! Many thanks! I found on the text where `\tmpa` was being called and commented out. It fixed the problem and didn't change the rest of the output. You, my lord, are a lifesaver! :)